# Dynamic layout for Multilple iOS devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I am developing an app in iOS.Earlier i was creating separate storyboards for separate iOS devices but now i am using Auto layout & Size classes for supporting multiple iOS devices.I have created a login screen.I have not specified any width or height of views But i have given leading space & trailing space,also the top & bottom space.This is sample image [image: enter image description here![enter image description here]

In image the size of image is expanded according to dimensions of iPad but i don't want it to image look too large.I want the same height & weight ratio as in iPhone.Please suggest how to do ?

Comment: Set Height and Width constriant to your image in storyboard..

Comment: But that does not look good on iPad if set image height & width for iPhone 3.5 inch screen then size looks fine but on iPad it looks too small.

Comment: In this case, make use of sizeclass change your storyboard to RegularWidth and AnyHeight and again set their height and width constraint. This constraints will be only for iPads not iPhones.

Comment: You can also set height *or* width and set an aspect ratio constraint.

Comment: agree with @Paulw11 if you want to maintain the height:width ratio then aspect ratio is a perfect solution for it....

Comment: Ok so i need to set the constraint for a particular size class not for all.So for that i also have to create separate constraints for all the devices as now i was using any width,any height?

Comment: Yes, aspect ratio is a easy option for you, if you are aware of it. Or else, give seperate constraint.

Comment: Hmm, But in that case i can't use other constraints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

all you need to set aspect ratio for maintaining the height:width according to screen size..check out images and constraints

[image]

as here, i give the aspect ratio 1:1 ...so according to screen size it maintains it..like below..

[image]

Comment: You have not specified the width & height here .

Comment: yes ...because here we set aspect ratio...so need to define width&height....aspect ratio automatically calculate Height and width according to ratio..

Comment: have you defined center horizontal & vertical constraint ?

Comment: Ok I have done it like you but it asking me to give width and height?
like expected width=196 actual=253 why ?when this will happen

Comment: ok give me your project...i'll check it...and tell you whats happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74714/discussion-between-bhavin-and-techguy).

Comment: see i used your method but still it's image size is incraesing too large

Answer (score 2):

[Learn to love Auto Layout](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/)
[image: 1st image]
[image: 2nd image]
[image: 3rd image]
[image: 4th image]

or if you want to [LEARN TO LOVE AUTO LAYOUT… PROGRAMMATICALLY](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)
This might helps you :)

Comment: Why you dod not specify bottom space on last button ?

Comment: Actually, the list of constraints that satisfied our requirement. So we don't need to add extra constraints.

Comment: [youtube Auto-layout vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1sc7NI6-wo&index=9&list=PLzvKpLTmBmzkeSIxxaswFqMhL3j_rSBtp)

This helps you a lots.

Answer (score 1):

I done it like this -Right click on object and Drag curser from your object to view controller you will see some option popup select equal hight from that pop up.

Comment: What does equal height means?

Comment: it is constraint you need to add then in the Document Outline and open the Attributes Inspector. If the First Item is not set to cloud.Height then select Reverse First and Second Item in the First Item dropdown select the Relation to be Less Than or Equal set Multiplier as per your req

Answer (score 1):

Use Image sets (Images.xcassets) and create device specific image.