# how to define constraint for equal width & height with aspect ratio?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, autolayout

I want to add square in my app with some height & width. Its height & width should vary with the screen size. As the same time it should be in the center of the screen.

Please tell me which constraint I should use?

I have sued equal height(0.7 multiplier), equal width(0.5) multiplier & aspect ratio & have aligned the view in center. But I get error for conflicting constraints.

Please suggest how I do it?

Comment: may be you want this.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510210/dynamic-layout-for-multilple-ios-devices/29510787#29510787

Comment: There is an aspect ratio constraint you can use. You would set it to 1:1. You wouldn't have to create constraints on the height and width. If you were going to constrain it's size you would only need one other constraint on either height or width

Comment: i want to vary height as well

Comment: take IBOutlet of constraint for height and width and then change the constraint as per your screen size on viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Comment: Add constraints to pin your object to the horizontal and vertical centre. Add constraints for leading and trailing space to inset from the edge of the screen as required. Add a 1:1 aspect ratio constraint

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11, though technically you only need 2 of the 3 horizontal constraints (horizontal centre, leading and trailing space).

Comment: @johnpatrickmorgan - you're right, actuallly specifying all 3 may give you a problem.